# On Stein manifolds and constant functions

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, several-complex-variables

Stein manifolds are defined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein_manifold#Definition

Obviously, M is Stein implies that there is a non-constant holomorphic function defined in it. Is the converse true? I mean, if there is at least one non-constant function over a manifold M, then it is Stein (given that it is Holomorphically Convex)?

If not, can someone point me a counter example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, take $M = \bar{\Bbb C} \times {\Bbb C}$. Then $M$ admits non-constant holomorphic functions, e.g. $f(z,w)=w$, is holomorphically convex, but doesn't separate points since every holomorphic function on $M$ is constant in the $z$-variable.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\bar{\mathbb C}$?  Is it just $\mathbb C$ with the opposite complex structure, i.e., the structure whose holomorphic functions are antiholomorphic in the usual sense?  If so, then $f(z,w) = \bar z$ is holomorphic on $M$ and not constant in $z$.

Comment: @JackLee I meant the Riemann sphere. (You can take any compact complex manifold instead and replace the second factor by any Stein manifold with the same argument.)

Comment: Ah, now I see. Thanks. Good answer.